# Index variable incorrect in onchange event

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to attach onchange event to select tags. 
There are multiple tags in a div.
So I'm using a for loop to attach events to each.
What I want to do is to update a select tag inside another container.
Basically it removes the "disabled" attribute from another select if user chooses an option other than default.

My problem is that the index variable, 'i' that is used in for loop is coming out incorrect while onchange triggers. 
The 'i' comes out to be what the last incremented value was.
As if it is acting like a global static variable.

I don't know how to search for this question so I'm creating a new one. I hope someone can help.

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z3U3Y/

this is code:

```
var screenprint = document.getElementsByClassName('screenprint')[0];

var sp = screenprint.getElementsByClassName('placements')[0].getElementsByTagName('select');

for (var i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
sp[i].onchange = function(t){

    if(this.value!==0){
        screenprint.getElementsByClassName('color')[0].getElementsByTagName('select')[i].disabled= false;
    }
    else{
        screenprint.getElementsByClassName('color')[0].getElementsByTagName('select')[i].disabled= true;
    }
```

Comment: I'm still not able to figure out how to implement it in my case.
But Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(this.value!==0){` is incorrect syntax. Should be `if(this.value!=0){`.

Also, when you open the Javascript console, it shows that : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of undefined`

Therefore there's an error with `screenprint.getElementsByClassName('color')[0].getElementsByTagName('select')[i]`, I don't think you're correctly referencing the `<select>` tags.

```
<div class="color">
            <h3>No. of colors</h3>
            <label >For 1st placement</label>
            <select disabled name="color">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
            </select>

        </div>
```

I recommend you `alert` each step of the element navigation to see where it becomes null and fix it from there.

Comment: Can you explain why it is incorrect syntax?

Comment: The !== operators performs a strict inequality comparisons. It does not attempt to convert the operands to compatible types before checking equality.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators

Comment: Yes, that's incorrect. Thanks for pointing it out. I'm used to strict tests now so I used that. Eventually it would have come out while testing.

Comment: @MrXenotype this is weird. I test for (value != 0) and it turns out false.
But if I do "0" then it works. Any idea why? This is supposed to work.

Comment: Check the value of SP[1] it might be null